# Computing the complement of sets in the product topology, is this always valid?

Tags: general-topology

I've seen this certain places while taking a course in topology, but I'm uncertain whether or not it's always a valid computation. Say you have the product topology on $X\times Y$, and you wish to compute the complement of $A\times B$ for $A \subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$, will it always be true that $(X\times Y)-(A\times B) = ((X-A)\times Y) \cup (X \times (Y-B))$? Written differently, $(X \times Y)\backslash(A\times B) = ((X\backslash A)\times Y) \cup (X\times (Y\backslash B))$?

Although I struggle to understand the definition of the general product topology, is it always valid there?

Comment: This looks like a question about sets to me. What is the link with topology?

Comment: This question is about the algebra of set operations, not about topology itself. Try to get the results of the RHS writing the LHS of the equality changing the set minus operator by it definition in terms of complementation and intersection. Then use De Morgan laws and the distribution property of intersection (or union) of sets over union (resp. intersection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let it be that $\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times Y$, $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq Y$.

$\langle x,y\rangle\notin A\times B$ if and only if $x\notin A$ or $y\notin B$.

$x\notin A$ and $y\in Y$ if and only if $\langle x,y\rangle\in (X-A)\times Y$.

$x\in X$ and $y\notin B$ if and only if $\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times (Y-B)$.

I hope this makes clear to you that indeed: $$(X\times Y)-(A\times B)=[(X-A)\times Y]\cup[X\times(Y-B)]$$

Nothing is said in this answer about topology, so I don't exclude that the answer does not really meets your needs.

Comment: Yes, it certainly did make it clear. I suppose I was thrown off by the fact that I saw it in examples and exercises in topology and forgot about basic set theory. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome.